# Trying to push Docker getting 'denied: requested access to the resource is denied' even though already logged in

Tags: docker

I have an image I've built locally but I'm not allowed to push it even though I am logged in.

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
voyen/client-management   latest              5c84a2c3546c        5 seconds ago       640MB
```

I then log in successfully and try to push it

```
$ docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: voyen
Password: 
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/andrei/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
$ docker push voyen/client-management:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/voyen/client-management]
3d081147e901: Preparing 
0027ee5a2387: Preparing 
19af2ea5c48a: Preparing 
b98fdbf8cf7f: Preparing 
ad6eaafe7ab3: Preparing 
57eab9d93a79: Waiting 
364be905de1c: Waiting 
6257fa9f9597: Waiting 
578414b395b9: Waiting 
abc3250a6c7f: Waiting 
13d5529fd232: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: do you have write permission to that repo?

Comment: I haven't set anything explicitly but I'm the creator of the repository. I assume I would already have write permissions, no?